# Selecting img to display based on a razor property value

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have 2 icons ("New" and "Preleased") with a property of "hidden" on my cshtml page.  I would like to display one or the other, based on the value of a property of the razor model I am returning.

my script is:

```
 function ItemConditionSelector() {
     if (@Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementItemCondition == "New") {
         document.getElementById("NewIcon").hidden = false;
     } else {
         document.getElementById("UsedIcon").hidden = false;
     }
 }
```

and my code block:

```
<td on="ItemConditionSelector()">
    @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementProduct
    <br /> @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementItemNumber | @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementProductSku |

    <img id="NewIcon" hidden src='~/Images/ico_NewMerchandise.png' />
    <img id="UsedIcon" hidden src='~/Images/ico_prelease.png' /> @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementItemCondition
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a css class that is `.hide { display: none; }`. Then you would do this:

```
<td on="ItemConditionSelector()">
    @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementProduct <br />
    @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementItemNumber | @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementProductSku | 
    @{
        var hideNew = @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementItemCondition == "New" ? "hide" : "";
        var hideUsed = hideNew == "hide" ? "" : "hide";
    }
    <img id="NewIcon" class="@hideNew" src='~/Images/ico_NewMerchandise.png' />
    <img id="UsedIcon" class="@hideUsed" src='~/Images/ico_prelease.png' />

    @Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementItemCondition
</td>
```

It's a bit of extra work to verify both like that, but it works.

Comment: In your opinion, why do you recommend this route over javascript or jquery?

Comment: This runs before any javascript so there would be no chance of content showing and then quickly hiding. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide the element at server side like this ...

```
if (@Model.InventoryExchangeItem.ReplacementItemCondition == "New") {
    <img id="NewIcon" class="@hideNew" src='~/Images/ico_NewMerchandise.png' />

}
else {
    <img id="UsedIcon" class="@hideUsed" src='~/Images/ico_prelease.png' />
}
```